# GATT Internal Error 129

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, bluetooth-gatt

I am using Marshmallow device to develop my BLE application. Many times I am getting status code 129 in the onServicesDiscovered() method. I have tested on 3 different devices, In all the devices I found the same issue. This is a random issue. I searched on many forums but didn't found any solutions yet.

Following are the things that I have tried: 
1. Refreshing Gatt cache using reflection.
2. Reinstalling application.
3. Unpairing and pairing the BLE device.
4. Turning On/Off Bluetooth and wifi.
Only restarting the phone is resolving this issue. But I can't ask a user to restart phone if the application is unable to make a connection to BLE device.

What is the root cause of this issue? Is there any
the solution for this?

I have checked the Android open source code also for this. I found following [URL for status codes](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/+/master/stack/include/gatt_api.h).

Please anyone provide me some hint or solution for this.

Comment: Please post the bt_snoop.hci log file, or some extraction of it, since it should display exactly what happens.